# Kernel Kmeans implementation

Tags: machine-learning, k-means, kernel

I'm currently trying to implement the Kernel Kmeans from scratch. At the time I'm writing this post, my implementation is perfectly working on nested circles dataset or even on Iris dataset (see pictures) :

[image]

[image]

But sometimes, the algorithm fails to classify very simple datasets. Like this one for example (I'm trying to have four clusters) :

[image]

I don't really know what is wrong with my implementation. I have also tried to implement different kernels (sigmoid, linear, polynomial, RBF etc...) for this case without success. Here is the general outline of the algorithm :

1. Compute the similarity matrix using the kernel function
2. Compute the index of the input in the transformed space using the similarity matrix (what I do here is that I sum up the line related to the input in the similarity matrix)
3. Choose random centroids in the transformed space using the array computed at step 2
4. Group inputs to the closest centroid in the transformed space
5. Calculate the new centroids
6. Repeat to step 4 still convergence

What I'm doing wrong ? Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't hear you say K-medioids.
Constraining (x, y) coordinates to match an observed point would be helpful,
if you're not already doing that for the last two examples.

I am struck by the symmetry between (.5, 4.5) and (4.5, .5),
and worry that our similarity measure doesn't really distinguish between them.
It looks like there are three classes, with red + green assigned to the middle one,
and for that middle class it was essentially a coin toss which color would
be assigned.

Please show us method and results for computing the similarity matrix.
(I would be more comfortable if we phrased this as some convenient
distance metric, such as L^2 norm.)
Also, plotting the centroids would help.
Even better would be to plot the track of how they converge across iterations.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the answer. I think you are right regarding the symmetry. After digging a little bit, the issue seems to come from the step 2 of my algorithm : "Compute the index of the input in the transformed space using the similarity matrix (what I do here is that I sum up the line related to the input in the similarity matrix)". What happens is that the points at the center are looking similar with this method, thus ending not properly classified. I have partially solved the issue by rescaling the dataset to [-1,1].